# @RepositoryRestResource doesnt export anything

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am trying to get RepositoryRestResource working but somehow it doesnt export anything.

Take this class:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "store", path = "store")
public interface StoreRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Store, Long> {
}
```

I expected to have a rest endpoint at http://localhost:8080/mycontext/stores or at http://localhost:8080/mycontext/store/1 or even get a service overview at http://localhost:8080/mycontext like described in the docs.

I can use this repository as "normal" from a controller with @Resource annotation and use it via the controller but i somehow dont get it to expose the REST endpoints.

Is there anything i need to do other than that? I added <jpa:repositories base-package="de.netstorsys.repositories" /> to the spring context because someone had it into his example code but with no difference.

Since the registration of the web endpoints is somehow spring magic, i dont know how to debug this further. Most of the Tutorials around that topic are for Spring Boot but i have a xml based standard spring application.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Can you post a little more about your application structure? Perhaps even as a project in github repository? Spring Data projects use scanning to find domain objects and repositories. By default, it uses the package where the app is based and descends from there. But there are also things you need to activate yourself if you're not using Spring Boot as well, and it's hard to discern from such a small fragment.

Comment: hard to post all because its too much, but the application is a fairly common xml based spring / spring-web-mvc application. I dont have a problem with repository scanning but i might need to include an XML equivalent to RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration (which is used in Spring Java Config)

Comment: Spring Data REST uses the dispatcher servlet, so its path is the root path. Furthermore SDR is the last one in the chain, i.e. any of your Spring MVC  mappings takes precedence over SDR. No magic is involved in the registration of the SDR web endpoints ;) Please note that you defined `collectionResourceRel = "store"`, not `stores` as in the URL you tried.

Comment: i tried every variant imaginable....

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might be missing file 
src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-data-rest/repositories-export.xml

where we specify:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

  <jpa:repositories base-package="<packageWhereRepoClassExists>"/>

</beans>
```

Please refer below sample spring-data-rest project, that is not based on spring-boot. It uses xml configuration:

https://github.com/charybr/spring-data-rest-acl

Answer (score 0):

I have one working example and blog that uses RepositoryRestResource and EntityLinks.  Please check if this helps you.  On the blog you will find GitHub link too.

http://sv-technical.blogspot.com/2015/11/spring-boot-and-repositoryrestresource.html